# I want to get only year/month/day in a correct format from my datatime type field in my table in SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table in SQL Server it has a `orderDate` column with `datetime` type

[image]

I use using `System.Globalization` in my asp.net page and use this code to get my system date history of solar format like this 1391/01/29 year/month/day:

```
 PersianCalendar pc=new PersianCalendar(); 
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now; 
 string year= pc.GetYear(dt).ToString();
 string month= pc.GetMonth(dt).ToString();
 string day= pc.GetDayOfMonth(dt).ToString();
```

and it works fine and then I store the date in my table and then write a select query in SQL Server it works fine but when I get this column value and show it in my grid view which uses `SqlDataSource` in another asp.net page it shows the result like this :

```
AM 12:00:00  9/1/1391
```

But it should show the result like

```
1391/09/01
```

I don't know why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Set the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) property on the bound field:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="<Your Date Field>" HeaderText="<Column Header>"
                DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"  />
```

Comment: thank you now it works fine.I have another question I used this command:SELECT min(id), [idfromIndex] FROM OrdersView WHERE [idfromIndex] IN(SELECT DISTINCT [idfromIndex] FROM OrdersView where IsObserve='True' and Ispay='True' and orderDate >='1390/09/01'  and orderDate <='1391/09/27' )  GROUP BY [idfromIndex]  .but if there is a record with exactly orderdate='1390/09/01' or orderdate='1391/09/27' it will not show them ,it only shows the result greater and lower than them

Comment: Cool, glad it works. If you don't mind please accept my answer when you get a chance. You should post your other question as a new distinct question.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can convert date value on server before passing to application.

```
SELECT replace(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120),'-','/') date
```